# Making a shortcut for a CMD command

Tags: cmd.exe

I run CMD commands like notepad++  or subl.exe  all the time, it would be easier if I'm able to do the same thing by writing np  or sb . Is there a way I can create a shortcut for an existing command in CMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to do:

Created a folded called shortcuts and just wrote a couple of.bat files there:

np.bat:

```
 notepad++ %1
```

sb.bat:

```
 subl.exe %1
```

These basically call a notpad++ or subl.exe and pass the first parameter they get.

Then I added that shortcuts folder to my PATH and now I can simply run these commands from anywhere.

Code is located here: https://github.com/naguibihab/useful-batch-files/tree/master/shortcuts

Comment: This is what we used to do before Windows. I once made a TUI that would run my batch scripts for all the daily things I used.

Comment: You should also look at [`doskey`](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) for creating macros.